# Sized-specific implementation?

Tags: rust

Is that possible to have several implementations of a trait, one for `T:Sized` another one for `T:Unsized`?

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fbda6f09cff5c8d1dc98063e597873ce)

Comment: Without specialization? No. But this looks like a XY problem.

Comment: Use case to have unified interface to get size of a memory. `core::mem::size_of` does not work for fat pointers.

Comment: You just want `core::mem::size_of_val()` then.

Comment: Okay that works. Thanks! So answer on the original question is "no"?

Comment: Pretty much. It _can_ be worked around/hacked/implemented more-or-less. But you don't want to do that.

Comment: So it is possible? Without nightly features?

Comment: <del>https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html. But don't. It is unsound.</del> This is using nightly.

Comment: There are other options, and other SO questions/answers presenting them. I just don't find them now.